# How to clear memory when remove view from WindowManager

Tags: android, memory, removechild, android-windowmanager

My app uses:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

I add the view to windowManager via code:

```
MyContextWrapper myContextWrapper= new MyContextWrapper(this);
// I created customview in myContextWrapper
View view = myContextWrapper.getView();

int FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED 
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION 
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH 
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD;
int type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, type,
                FLAG, PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
mWindowManager.addView(view, params);
```

How do I clear memory of the view when I remove it? I want to clear it because memory increased after new MyContextWrapper(this) getview and add to mWindowManager.

```
 mWindowManager.removeView(view);
```

myContextWrapper.getView() include (ImageView, ViewPager...)

Comment: You don't need to clear the memory after you removed the view, because `Java` has garbage collector which will do this stuff for you. Simply saying, if this view has no references to it, it will be removed from the heap automatically.

Comment: clear its cache, flush the layout by its resources, and remove all drawables from it and nullify it.

Comment: @nikis my app has use services, if don't clear ram then app uses very much ram, it's about 150mb :(

Comment: @ThoTran Did you find any solution?